# kinect v2 pitch and yaw of the head in processing 2.2.1 kinectPV2 library

Tags: processing, kinect

I'm currently working on my MSc project using Kinect V2 and I'm using processing 2.2.1 (KinectPV2 library) because I prefer using processing more than C# .. I'll appreciate your help so much

how can I get the pitch and yaw of the head? (this is available in C#)